# How can I separate the letter in string when drawing

Tags: java, draw, drawstring

I want to draw a string that I take from a jtextarea, but I want to draw with 20px space to each letter, but I think I can't do this with drawstring and I can't draw a char per time with drawchars, so what can I do?

I want to write a letter above each trace, but how I'm doing know is not working

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);
    for(int i=0;i<PalavraAdivinha.length();i++)
    {
        g.fillRect(InicioTraco+(i*40), 240, 40, 5);
    }
    Font titulo = new Font("Arial",Font.BOLD,40);
    g.setFont(titulo);
    g.drawString("Adivinhe a palavra", 0,100 );
    if(PalavraDigitada != null)
    {
        g.drawString(PalavraDigitada, InicioTraco, 235);
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to consider using a monospaced font.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can draw each character seperately. By retrieving the `FontMetrics` currently used by the `Graphics` object, you can measure the width of each character, so you can advance using this width and a given seperation.

```
public static void drawString(Graphics g, String string, int x, int y,
        int seperation) {

    FontMetrics metrics = g.getFontMetrics();
    int drawx = x;

    for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); ++i) {
        String character = "" + string.charAt(i);

        g.drawString(character, drawx, y);
        drawx += seperation + metrics.stringWidth(character);
    }
}
```

**Example Code**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(512, 256,
            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        drawString(g, "i am drawn with seperation " + i, 24, 24 + 16 * i, i);
    ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("output.png"));
}
```

**Result**

[image: Several strings with increasing amounts of seperation]

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh, did like u, using ur fuction but still goting java.lang.NullPointerException do u have any ideia y?

Comment: already find out the problem, using wrong variable.length() :D Thanks for the answer! Was really helpfull!